# SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined Php PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I have been stumped by this error i am trying validate user that if username or email is already in the table.please help....

```
function checkDuplicateEntries($table,$column_name,$value,$db){

   try {

       $sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM " .$table."WHERE".$column_name."=:$column_name";

       $statement = $db->prepare($sqlQuery);

       $statement->execute(array(':$column_name'=> $value));

       if($row=$statement->fetch()){

           return true;
       }
       return false;

   }catch (PDOException $ex){

       echo"error while checking for duplicate entries".$ex->getMessage();

   }


 }


 if(checkDuplicateEntries("users","email",$email,$db)){

            $result = flashMessage("Email is already taken please try another one");
        }


else if(checkDuplicateEntries("users","username",$username,$db)){

        $result = flashMessage("Username is already taken please try another one");
    }
```

Comment: What is the output of this ?

Comment: Make sure you know the difference between single and double quotes.

Comment: error while checking for duplicate entriesSQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not definederror while checking for duplicate entriesSQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Comment: You need space between table name and where clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that you use single quotes on execute() call:

```
$statement->execute(array(':$column_name'=> $value));
```

Switch it to a double quotes and try again.
Please also take a look at: [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Comment: In your situation in the `$sqlQuery` condition you use double quotes, so `$column_name` value will be extracted. But then you use single quotes on execute, so value will be not extracted and pdo will see `:$column_name`, not value of that variable. Please attentively read info on the link that I provided, and you have no this issue again.